# Boolean algebra - Finding an item exists or not?

Tags: c#, php, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I have the following items

Apple=   00000001  (1)

Mango=    00000010  (2)

Banana=   00000100  (4)

Grapes=      00001000  (8)

Now I am storing the fruits a user can have like this by doing or'd

UserA- 00000001(Apple) or'd 00000010(Mango) = 00000011 (i.e 3)

Now I want to check whether that user contains Apple or Banana ? Till now I am thinking this : (UserA's-Values) & (Apple|Banana ) =(Apple|Banana )

i.e (00000011)&(00000001|00000100 ) =(00000001|00000100 )

but it is not working ? May I know what I am missing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're checking for Apple AND Banana. The expression should be (UserA's-Values) & (Apple|Banana) (!= 0)

Answer (score 0):

Bits can be stored and manipulated in both Enum and Struct as well.

For Enum: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx 
For Struct: [Bit fields in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464/bit-fields-in-c)

Enums are nice as `.ToString()` will print a coma-separated list of the elements, but you still use standard AND/OR operators to manipulate and test against it.