# C# deserializing a binary structure with bitfields - how to do?

Tags: c#, c, struct, binary-deserialization

I have a C struct that is defined in a way similar to this:

```
struct TestStruct
{
    uint flag1 :2;
    uint flag2 :2;
    uint flag3 :2;
    uint flag4 :2;

    uint value1;
} TestStruct;
```

I know that I can deserialize a binary struct by using the `StructLayout` attribute and `Marshal.PtrToStructure()`. But is there a way to do this with binary fields as shown in the structure where one value is just 2 bits long?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct support for such a structure in C#. You have to use an integral type holding all the bits and extract the fields from it afterwards.

See the solution to a very similar problem at [Bit fields in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464/bit-fields-in-c)

Comment: Well not exactly what I was looking for, but it doesn't get any better as I've seen now with C#... Thanks!