# C Bit fields in C#

Tags: c#, c, bit-manipulation, code-conversion

I need to translate a C struct to C# which uses bit fields.

```
typedef struct foo  
{  
    unsigned int bar1 : 1;
    unsigned int bar2 : 2;
    unsigned int bar3 : 3;
    unsigned int bar4 : 4;
    unsigned int bar5 : 5;
    unsigned int bar6 : 6;
    unsigned int bar7 : 7;
    ...
    unsigned int bar32 : 32;
} foo;
```

Anyone knows how to do this please?

Comment: Already answered in [Bit fields in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464/bit-fields-in-c).

Comment: I hope you are aware of that you are allocating 1+2+3.. +32 bits = 528 bits = 66 bytes.

Comment: @Lundin: It is just an example, I just wanted to point out that I have all possible bit field variants.

Comment: @Aasmund Eldhuset: Yes I have already seen this post but I don't get it why he converts all uints into one long.

Comment: @David I guess he just wanted to demonstrate that the bit mask ended up as desired, and he assumed that "64 bits should be enough for anyone"... ;-) However, his solution does not save any space (I didn't realize that until now), since each element of his struct is a full uint. If you really need to conserve space or need to communicate with hardware (which I guess are the only defendable reasons for using bit fields in the first place), you should consider using `BitArray` as suggested by @Nekresh, and perhaps wrap it in properties that get/set bit groups (quite a bit of work, though).

Comment: Are you trying to marshal the data? If not, you could just write your own `BitField` class which would be very simple.

Comment: I guess you need to clarify HOW you intent to use this `struct` first.

Answer (score 8):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8480/1345223) and [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229062.aspx), you may be looking for the following instead of a `BitField`

```
[Flags]
enum Foo
{
    bar0 = 0,
    bar1 = 1,
    bar2 = 2,
    bar3 = 4,
    bar4 = 8,
    ...
}
```

as that can be a bit annoying to calculate out to 2<sup>32</sup>, you can also do this:

```
[Flags]
enum Foo
{
    bar0 = 0,
    bar1 = 1 << 0,
    bar2 = 1 << 1,
    bar3 = 1 << 2,
    bar4 = 1 << 3,
    ...
}
```

And you can access your flags as you would expect in C:

```
Foo myFoo |= Foo.bar4;
```

and C# in .NET 4 throws you a bone with the `HasFlag()` method.

```
if( myFoo.HasFlag(Foo.bar4) ) ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `BitArray` class for the framework. Look at the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) article.

Comment: Thanks, but that would be pain in the ass if I have to declare every single bit.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately there is no such thing in C#. The closest thing is applying a StructLayout attribute and using FieldOffset attribute on fields. However the field offset is in **bytes**, not in bits. Here is an example:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct MyStruct
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int Foo; // this field's offset is 0 bytes

    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public int Bar; // this field's offset is 2 bytes. It overlaps with Foo.
}
```

But it is NOT the same as the functionality you want.

If what you need is to decode a bits sequence to a struct you will have to write manual code (using, for example, using classes like MemoryStream or BitConverter).

Comment: >If what you need is to decode a bits sequence to a struct you will have to write manual code (using, for example, using classes like MemoryStream or BitConverter).  
Well that was what I was looking for.

Answer (score -2):

Are you looking for the `FieldOffset` attribute? See here: [FieldOffsetAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.fieldoffsetattribute.aspx)