# Read bits between bytes

Tags: c, memory, bit

I am trying to read bits from a buffer of bytes. So far masking and shifting has worked however I am not sure what to do about a value that appear between bytes, such as,

```
... 11001001 11101101 ... (read 8 bits from the buffer with 4 bit offset)
        |_______|
```

8 and 4 are not static, can differ, for example:

```
... 11001001 11101101 ... (read 7 bits from the buffer with 6 bit offset)
    ^     |______|       
    |
  Buffer
```

I have a starting offset, and a total of bits to read. However I have a char buffer, and I can't bit shift two bytes into one by using chars (Or maybe I can ?), so I thought of doing this:

```
uint16_t two_byte_buffer;
memcpy(&two_byte_buffer, real_buffer, 2); // May need to endian convert ?
```

And now I can bit-shift the 16-bit integer value to read the necessary 8 bits. Would this method work ? And is there a better method ?

**Edit:** So far I have used this method to extract bits from a single char.

[Reading n-bits from a 32bit chunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481929/reading-n-bits-from-a-32bit-chunk)

Comment: Can you please tell what you are trying to do?

Comment: `And now I can bit-shift the 16-bit integer value to read the necessary 8 bits` - and you can't do it with `real_buffer`? How is `real_buffer` defined? `I can't bit shift two bytes into one by using chars` `uint8_t value = ((real_buffer[1] << 4) & 0xf0) | ((real_buffer[0] >> 4) & 0x0f)` ?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am parsing a bit-encoded file.

Comment: @KamilCuk A char is 8-bits, I don't need to shift a 8 bit value, I need to shift an at least 16-bit value to get the bits in the next char. `real_buffer` is just a `char*`, but it doesn't represent ascii values, just binary data.

Comment: Writing to a `uint16_t` seems like the best method.  Instead of `memcpy` I'd use `two_byte_buffer = (real_buffer[n] << 8) | real_buffer[n + 1]`.

Comment: @KamilCuk The offset and the read_count are variable, I would probably need a mask table to write what you written in the comment programmatically.

Comment: Please clarify your question then. You want to write a function like `int extract(char *result, char *buffer, size_t offset_in_bits, size_t length_in_bits)` that would place in the buffer pointed to by result the bits extract from the buffer pointed to bu `buffer` from specified bit position in specified bits length? That is very different job (and a much much bigger one) then extracting just const 8 bits from a const 4 bits offset. So you said: `now I can bit-shift ...` and `So far masking and shifting has worked` - please post the code that worked.

Comment: @KamilCuk Exactly, sorry if it wasn't clear before.

Comment: Why can't you just use the two chars?

Comment: @KamilCuk The buffer is not being pointed to by a bit index. It's first_byte + bit_offset

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BIG_ENDIAN_BUFFER

#ifdef BIG_ENDIAN_BUFFER
  #define EXTRACT(BUFFER, OFFSET) ((((BUFFER[0] << 8) | BUFFER[1]) >> (8 - OFFSET)) & 0xFF)
#else
  #define EXTRACT(BUFFER, OFFSET) ((((BUFFER[1] << 8) | BUFFER[0]) >> (8 - OFFSET)) & 0xFF)
#endif

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t real_buffer[] = {0xC9, 0xED};

    printf("0x%02X, 0x%02X, 0x%02X\n", real_buffer[0], real_buffer[1], EXTRACT(real_buffer, 0));
    printf("0x%02X, 0x%02X, 0x%02X\n", real_buffer[0], real_buffer[1], EXTRACT(real_buffer, 1));
    printf("0x%02X, 0x%02X, 0x%02X\n", real_buffer[0], real_buffer[1], EXTRACT(real_buffer, 2));
    printf("0x%02X, 0x%02X, 0x%02X\n", real_buffer[0], real_buffer[1], EXTRACT(real_buffer, 3));
    printf("0x%02X, 0x%02X, 0x%02X\n", real_buffer[0], real_buffer[1], EXTRACT(real_buffer, 4));
    printf("0x%02X, 0x%02X, 0x%02X\n", real_buffer[0], real_buffer[1], EXTRACT(real_buffer, 5));
    printf("0x%02X, 0x%02X, 0x%02X\n", real_buffer[0], real_buffer[1], EXTRACT(real_buffer, 6));
    printf("0x%02X, 0x%02X, 0x%02X\n", real_buffer[0], real_buffer[1], EXTRACT(real_buffer, 7));
    printf("0x%02X, 0x%02X, 0x%02X\n", real_buffer[0], real_buffer[1], EXTRACT(real_buffer, 8));

    return 0;
}
```

When `BIG_ENDIAN_BUFFER` is `define`d:

```
0xC9, 0xED, 0xC9
0xC9, 0xED, 0x93
0xC9, 0xED, 0x27
0xC9, 0xED, 0x4F
0xC9, 0xED, 0x9E
0xC9, 0xED, 0x3D
0xC9, 0xED, 0x7B
0xC9, 0xED, 0xF6
0xC9, 0xED, 0xED
```

When `BIG_ENDIAN_BUFFER` is NOT `define`d:

```
0xC9, 0xED, 0xED
0xC9, 0xED, 0xDB
0xC9, 0xED, 0xB7
0xC9, 0xED, 0x6E
0xC9, 0xED, 0xDC
0xC9, 0xED, 0xB9
0xC9, 0xED, 0x72
0xC9, 0xED, 0xE4
0xC9, 0xED, 0xC9
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, just to inform, the value being tried to extracted can be smaller than 8 bits.

Comment: I see... number of bits is variable.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need memcpy to 16 bit to be able to extract. Try this, it works on arbitrary length char arrays. It allocates sufficient memory to hold the extracted bits.

```c
#import <stdlib.h>
#import <stdio.h>
#import <string.h>

char buffer[] = "whatever";
int offset_bits = 12;
int count_bits = 34;
char* result;

void print_bits(char* buf, int nbits){
    for (int i = 0; i<nbits; i++){
        printf("%i",(buf[i/8]>>(i%8))&1);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(){
    int offset_bytes = offset_bits/8;
    int shift_bits = offset_bits%8;
    int count_bytes = (count_bits-1)/8+1;
    result = (char*) malloc( sizeof(char)*count_bytes );
    for(int i=0; i<count_bytes ;i++){
        result[i] = (buffer[i+offset_bytes]>>shift_bits) ^ (buffer[i+offset_bytes+1]<<(8-shift_bits));
    }
    print_bits(buffer, 8*strlen(buffer));
    for(int i=0; i<offset_bits ;i++){printf(" ");}
    print_bits(result, count_bits);

    return 1;
}
```

This should output

```
1110111000010110100001100010111010100110011011101010011001001110
            0110100001100010111010100110011011
```

I have aligned the extracted bits (34 in this example) by the offset, so one can visually check the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uint32_t extractBytes(void *val, unsigned startBit, unsigned nBits)
{
    uint32_t *v32 = val;
    uint32_t mask = (1 << nBits) - 1;

    return (*v32 >> startBit) & mask;
}

int main()
{
    uint32_t x = 0b111101000;

    printf("0x%x\n", extractBytes(&x, 3, 4));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/vqfMDK

for 64 bits just change the types

Comment: This supports a maximum of 32 bits. OP seeks a general solution for arbitrary length arrays.

Comment: general solution for 64bits+ is not practiacally needed

Comment: How can you tell without knowing about the use case?

Comment: @ilmiacs because it is easly done with smaller chunks and C does not support any data >64bits at this moment