# C# - How can I sort the fields returned by Type.GetFields() by their declaration order?

Tags: c#, reflection

[Type.GetFields()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch9714z3.aspx) does not return fields in a particular order, but I want to sort them by declaration order. How can I do that? I didn't see an 'index' property in FieldInfo or anything with similar functionality.

Motivation: I want to implement a bitfield solution similar to the one in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14591/192359), but as mentioned in the second comment there, the order is not guaranteed.

**EDIT :** clarification - I don't want to create this code to rely on this ordering. I want to create this code to parse existing binary data which already has certain ordering.

---

**EDIT 2 (post answer):** I have selected an answer which fully answers the question, and which worked properly on my tests, but just as a side note, the bitfield solution is problematic:

When reading the value from the bit field you get an unsigned integer (of some size), but then you can't cast it properly according to the actual field type (byte, bool, int) which you get at runtime from the FieldInfo. You can do it with runtime explicit conditionals (`if type.Equals(typeof(bool))` etc.), but that's a bit ugly.

I ended up using C++/CLI which made this so much simpler.

Comment: What is the "declaration order", in the face of such features as partial classes? If you want a defined, explicit, order, alphabetical would seem a simpler one to aim for.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - see clarification above.

Comment: @Asaf - looking at the binary is a dangerous way to go as the compiler may optimize things differently.

Comment: @DanielA.White - Not the 'executable binary', but binary data with a certain format which was saved by an external tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a position information to the attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class BitfieldAttribute : Attribute 
{ 
    public BitfieldAttribute(int position, int length) 
    { 
        this.Position = position; 
        this.Length = length; 
    } 

    public int Position { get; private set; }

    public int Length { get; private set; }
}
```

Then you can iteratate through the fields like this

```
foreach (FieldInfo fld in type.GetFields().OrderBy(f => f.Position)) {
    ...
}
```

This attribute would be used like this

```
struct PESHeader 
{ 
    [Bitfield(0, 2)] 
    public uint reserved; 

    [Bitfield(1, 2)] 
    public uint scrambling_control; 

    [Bitfield(2, 1)] 
    public uint priority; 

    [Bitfield(3, 1)] 
    public uint data_alignment_indicator; 

    [Bitfield(4, 1)] 
    public uint copyright; 

    [Bitfield(5, 1)] 
    public uint original_or_copy; 
}
```

---

The advantage over an alphabetical order is that you can control the position of new fields that you add later and thus avoid that the position of existing fields changes.

Answer (score 5):

You could write an custom attribute that declares the order. Then for each field, look up that attribute. Use the values to sort.

It wouldn't be automatic, but it would be a very deterministic way.

Example of usage:

```
[Index(0)]
private int myField;

[Index(1)]
private int myOtherField;
```

Comment: It's possible, but it's a hassle. Each field will also need the bitfield attribute, and I can just name the fields such that it allows me to sort it by name without writing an extra class.

Comment: @Asaf: That forces you to use potentially-non-ideal names, *and* means that someone refactoring later could mess things up without realizing. I would urge you to use this solution - make each piece of information mean *one thing*.

Comment: @Asaf - you could always combine the bitfield attribute with this.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the BitFieldLength attribute like this:

```
sealed class BitfieldLengthAttribute : Attribute
{
    uint index;
    uint length;

    public BitfieldLengthAttribute(uint index, uint length)
    {
        this.index = index;
        this.length = length;
    }

    public uint Index { get { return index; } }
    public uint Length { get { return length; } }
}
```

Then manually add an index to all fields, retreive the types in a list and sort the list on the attribute index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to Object and write a code like this:

```
var fields = type.GetFields().OrderBy(f => f.Name).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

At this [link](http://www.sebastienmahe.com/v3/seb.blog/2010/03/08/c-reflection-getproperties-kept-in-declaration-order/) its says to sort by the MetadataToken to get the declaration order.

which means something like:

```
IEnumerable<FieldInfo> fields = t.GetFields().OrderBy(f=>f.MetadataToken);
```

I dont really understand how its work but for now its worked fine for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Links can break, and as such link-only answers are discouraged. Including the key parts from the link is strongly recommended.