# How to represent bits in structure in c#

Tags: c#, byte, bit

I have a byte that represents two values.
        First bit represents represents the sequence number.
        The rest of the bits represent the actual content.

In C, I could easily parse this out by the following:

```
typedef struct 
{
    byte seqNumber : 1;
    byte content   : 7;
}
MyPacket;
```

Then I can easily case the input to MyPacket:

```
char* inputByte = "U"; // binary 01010101
MyPacket * myPacket = (MyPacket*)inputByte;
```

Then 
    myPacket->seqNumber = 1
    myPacket->content = 42

How can I do the same thing in C#?

Thank you
kab

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bit fields in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464/bit-fields-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks m-y!
It looks like a good method. I will work on that method when I get some time, but for now, I will use the method proposed by Jon Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use properties.  Make getters and setters for the two parts that modify the appropriate bits in the true representation.

```
class myPacket {
  public byte packed = 0;
  public int seqNumber {
    get { return value >> 7; }
    set { packed = value << 7 | packed & ~(1 << 7); } 
  }
  public int content {
    get { return value & ~(1 << 7); }
    set { packed = packed & (1 << 7) | value & ~(1 << 7); } 
  }
}
```

C# likes to keep its types simple, so I am betting this is the closest you are getting.  Obviously it does not net you the performance improvement in C, but it salvages the meanings.

Comment: This is a good idea.
For the get property for seqNumber, i am using (packed >> 0) & 1
For the get property for content, i am using (packed >> 1) & 127

Comment: That puts the bits in the opposite order you claimed, no?  I am used to a world where the first bit is most-significant.  
Also, surely the (packed >> 0) is unnecessary, as that does nothing.

Comment: C++ uses Big-Endian order, so the seqNumber will have the least significant bit (starting from the right)
To get that, I have to use (packed >> 0) & 1
I think that's how it works. Let me know if you find otherwise. Thanks!

Comment: (packed & 1) would do as well, it chooses the low-order bit of the variable packed.