# Convert byte[] to sbyte[]

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I tried to convert an Array from `byte[]` to `sbyte[]`.

Here is my sample Array:

```
byte[] unsigned = { 0x00, 0xFF, 0x1F, 0x8F, 0x80 };
```

I already tried this:

```
sbyte[] signed = (sbyte[])((Array)unsigned);
```

But it doesn't work. There is no value in the array after this operation.

Does anybody has an better idea?

Comment: This code works in the sense that it compiles and throws no error. It results in an array that can be used as `sbyte[]` in nearly every situation, but is still marked as `byte[]` by the runtime. Not sure what you mean by "there is no value in the array", for me the array is `{0, -1, 31, -113, -128}` as expected.

Comment: After compiling there is no value in the signed array. Visual Studio shows "?" in every element of the signed array.

Comment: Ok, I try to get an element from the signed array and it still works. Thanks for your help. I try to use this solution.

Comment: Then that's a VS limitation. VS might not understand that an array with static type `sbyte[]` but a dynamic type `byte[]` is valid. The CLR allows this cast, but C# does not. This is a hack, so in most applications you'll want to use @Selman's suggestion.

Comment: It's just the debugger that has problems with displaying it, as it's really a `sbyte[]` reference to a `byte[]`.

Comment: Something like `(sbyte[])(object)ubytes` as you've tried works fine, just looks funny in the debugger.

Comment: @Selmann22 No need to delete the whole answer. The second part is correct, though I'd prefer `sbyte[] signed = Array.ConvertAll(unsigned, x => unchecked((sbyte)x));` so it works even if checked arithmetic is enabled.

Comment: Why do you answer the question using comments?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
sbyte[] signed = (sbyte[]) (Array) unsigned;
```

This works because byte and sbyte have the same length in memory and can be converted without the need to alter the memory representation.

This method might, however, lead to some weird bugs with the debugger. If your byte array is not very big, you can use `Array.ConvertAll` instead.

```
sbyte[] signed = Array.ConvertAll(unsigned, b => unchecked((sbyte)b));
```

Comment: I'd use `unchecked((sbyte)b)` so it works even if checked arithmetic is enabled. It also serves as documentation that overflows are intentional and not just a performance optimization.

Comment: My memory told me that overflow checks do not apply to bytes/sbytes. I might have been wrong. **EDIT:** fixed now :)

Comment: Casting 255 to `sbyte` certainly throws with checked arithmetic. What might have confused you is that `(byte)255 + (byte)255` does not throw, since the operands get promoted to `int` where it does not overflow.

Comment: Possibly, I fixed it either way. Thank you for pointing this out :)

Answer (score 5):

How about using [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy(v=vs.110).aspx)? The good thing about this answer is that avoids cast checking on a byte by byte basis. The bad thing about this answer is that avoids cast checking on a byte by byte basis.

```
var unsigned = new byte[] { 0x00, 0xFF, 0x1F, 0x8F, 0x80 };
var signed = new sbyte[unsigned.Length];
Buffer.BlockCopy(unsigned, 0, signed, 0, unsigned.Length);
```

This just copies the bytes, values above `byte.MaxValue` will have a negative `sbyte` value.

Takes two lines of code but should be quick.

Comment: No need for the `@`. `signed`/`unsigned` aren't keywords in C#.

Comment: @CodesInChaos SO led me astray.

Answer (score 1):

Easily do like this:

```
sbyte[] signed = unsigned.Select(b=>(sbyte)b).ToArray();
```

I'm not sure about syntax. check verify it.

Comment: This works. But 1) `ConvertAll` is faster and just as readable 2) I prefer `unchecked((sbyte)b)`. See @Sepehr's answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

old .net framework and old .net core don't support reinterpret_cast ,but support * pointer and unsafe code.
new .net version add system.memory library, can solutions this question and copy memory.

```
   byte[] unsigned = { 0x00, 0xFF, 0x1F, 0x8F, 0x80 };  
   ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytesBuffer = unsigned;
   ReadOnlySpan<sbyte> sbytesBuffer = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, sbyte>(bytesBuffer);
   sbyte[] signed = sbytesBuffer.ToArray();
```