# Using nibbles in struct C#

Tags: c#, c++, struct

Can we work with nibbles in C# struct like C++?. 
Is there any equivalent code in C#?

```
typedef struct PHeader {
    #if defined(LITTLE_ENDIAN)
        uint8_t         mHdrLen  :4;
        uint8_t         mVer     :4;
    #elif defined (BIG_ENDIAN)
        uint8_t         mVer    :4;         
        uint8_t         mHdrLen :4;        
    #endif
     }
```

Thank You.

Comment: POssible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464/bit-fields-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve same result using `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]` and `FieldOffset` attribute. You can read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.fieldoffsetattribute.fieldoffsetattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

But please note that `FieldOffset` works in byte unit, not bit.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct X
{
#if A
    [FieldOffset(0)] public byte a;
    [FieldOffset(1)] public byte b;
#else
    [FieldOffset(0)] public byte b;
    [FieldOffset(1)] public byte a;
#endif
}
```

Example:

```
unsafe
{
    short x = 12300;
    X* y = (X*)&x;
    X t = *y;

    Console.WriteLine(t.a + " - " + t.b);
}
```

If you run that code with undefined A, you will get result `48 - 12` but if you `#define A`, then you will get result `12 - 48`.