# How to convert a short to a bool[]?

Tags: c#

How can I convert a short to an array of booleans (bool[]) in C#? I'm looking for an algorithm, multiple options would be appreciated with their pros and cons.

So for example if I have a short that = 132 that is 10000100 in binary

So I want an array of {false, false, true, false, false, false, false, true }

```
bool[] ToArrayOfBool(short source)
{
    bool[] result = new bool[16];

    ///Do Some stuff here


    return result;
}
```

Comment: You want to convert a short number to a binary representation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464/bit-fields-in-c-sharp not necessarily an exact duplicate, but certainly relevant.

Comment: Input output example added. Sorry

Comment: Why all the down votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    // Single bit bitmask at index i: 0b0001, 0b0010, 0b0100 etc..
    int bitmask = 1 << i;
    // Check to see if the bit at that mask is set.
    result[i] = (source & bitmask) != 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [BitArray class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
byte input = 132;
var bits = new BitArray(new byte[] { input });
foreach (var b in bits)
{
    Console.WriteLine(b);
}
```

This produces an `IEnumerable<bool>` but you can also convert it to an array:

```
byte input = 132;
var bits = new BitArray(new byte[] { input }).Cast<bool>().ToArray();
foreach (var b in bits)
{
    Console.WriteLine(b);
}
```

Output:

```
False
False
True
False
False
False
False
True
```

You can also just leave it as a `short`, and get the bits you need using an extension method like this one:

```
public static bool GetBit(this short This, int bitNumber)
{
    return (This & (1 << bitNumber)) != 0;
}

for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(input.GetBit(i));
}
```

[Example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1TMq5F)

Comment: In a standard bit interpretation of a decimal, isn't the most significant bit supposed to come first? For example, I would expect the output above to be 132 = 10000100.

Comment: For example, referencing your last example and dotnet fiddle... I would expect something like `(decimal & ( 1 << (8-i))) != 0` which preserves the standard bit interpretation (most-significant-bit first) of the decimal. Your example seems to convert to a least-significant-bit first interpretation.

Comment: The issue is not LSB or MSB. The issue is your definition of the word "first." Bits in a byte are typically numbered from 0 to 7 *from right to left*. The numbers correspond to the power of 2, e.g. bit 0 is 2^0, bit 1 is 2^1, and bit 7 is 2^7. The 7th bit is the most significant (and is typically "first," i.e. leftmost, within a byte, when written out).

Comment: "Bits in a byte are typically numbered from 0 to 7 from right to left." ...
Yes, so assuming a 'typical' interpretation as you stated, shouldn't your code output the bool array (right to left) 10000100 instead of 00100001 to represent the decimal 132?

I think we are on the same page on what "first" [means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Most-_vs_least-significant_bit_first).

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Console.WriteLine($"132 = {string.Join(",", ConvertToArray(132))}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static bool[] ConvertToArray(short @short)
        {
            var result = new bool[16];
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            {
                result[i] = (@short & (short)1) == (short)1 ? true : false;
                @short = (short)(@short >> 1);
            }
            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

clue

```
var bits = new bool[16];
if(i &x0001) bits[0] = true;
if(i &x0002) bits[1] = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have three steps:

1. Convert to binary first using [`Convert.ToString(myshort, 2)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1kwkfdz(v=vs.110).aspx) where `myshort` is your value.
2. Loop through each character of the string and test if it equals 1 and add each to a `bool` array.
3. Reverse the array (or you can reverse the string after step 1)

Because I'm bored, here's an example :)

```
    short myshort = 132;
    Console.WriteLine("Short: " + myshort);

    var binarystring = Convert.ToString(myshort, 2);
    Console.WriteLine("Binary: " + binarystring);

    var boolarray = new bool[binarystring.Length];

    for (var i = 0; i < binarystring.Length; i++) {
        boolarray[i] = binarystring[i] == '1';          
    }

    Array.Reverse(boolarray);

    //output result     
    foreach (var b in boolarray) {
        Console.Write(b.ToString() + ", ");
    }
```

The output is:

```
Short: 132
Binary: 10000100
False, False, True, False, False, False, False, True,
```

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to @pm100 this is what I came up with

```
public bool[] ToArrayOfBool(short source)
{
    bool[] result = new bool[16];

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        result[i] = (source & (i * i)) == i * i; 
    }

    return result;
}
```