# How to insert a byte into an int starting at X position

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bit

I have an Int32 that is broken in to different sections, each with its own value.

Lets say I have:

```
byte version = 0x02
uInt32 packedValues = 0;
```

How can I put the 0x02 in packedValues, starting at index 20, or any index.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the layout of this int32? Is it a bunch of bit flags or do you intend to have multibit fields?

Comment: Multibig fields I guess? Like on the decoder side, for example bits 11-13 is a sequence number. So to decode it, the other end would just look at  those bits bits, then cast it to a number. So if the sequence is bit11-13 is "0x111", the number casted should be decimal 7.

Comment: Why not use a struct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bit fields in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464/bit-fields-in-c-sharp)

Comment: My personal inclination would be to define field masks and apply those to the unit32: `unit32 fieldA = 0x3; // Lowest 2 bits, etc.`

Comment: Right, I was going that route. So to set fieldA i would just OR then together no? packedValues = packedValues | fieldA ?  No bitshifting is required, i think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what do you mean by index but it seems that you need to do some bit twiddling. Something along these lines:

```cs
byte version = 0x02;
var index = 20;
uint packedValues = 0;

var b1 = version << index;
packedValues = (uint)((packedValues & ~(0xFF << index)) | (uint)(version << index));
```

`(packedValues & ~(0xFF << index))` - zeroes needed bits and the rest sets the bits from the source.

Comment: Bit twiddling rather than bit arithmetic. There isn't much arithmetic in `&` `|` `~` and `<<`. Good answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can us a `span<byte>` to convert your int to a collection of bytes. Can't test right now but something like

```
Span<byte> bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(packedValues);

bytes[20] = 0x02;

uint32 packedValues = BitConverter.ToInt32(ItemLengthBytes);
```

Comment: `BitConverter.GetBytes` will return 4 bytes, so `[20]` would result in an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.